# Please verify my proof: If $a$ and $b$ are irrational, then $a^b$ is irrational.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

I would like to prove or disprove the following statement:

> If $a$ and $b$ are both irrational, then $a^b$ must be irrational.

I disproved the statement by giving a **counter-example**. It follows:

> Let $a = \sqrt{10}$ and $b = \log(4)$. In this case, both $a$,$b$ $∉$ $\mathbb {Q}$.
>   So $a^b = (\sqrt{10})$$^{(\log(4))}=2\in\mathbb {Q}$. Therefore, the statement is false.

Am I answering this in a right way? Please help!

Comment: The following slick proof is elementary and doesn't require one to prove the irrationality of $\log n$. 

Consider $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt 2}$. If this is rational, we're done. If it's irrational, then 

$$\left(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt 2}\right)^{\sqrt 2}$$ 

is an example.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 +1 if you post this as an answer.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 My computer shut down while writing out my answer, and so your comment beat me to it :)

Comment: Your proof is correct but you need to justify that $\sqrt{10}$ and $\log(4)$ are irrational.

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is just fine! What warrants statement here though is the classic non-constructive proof that your statement is false. We start with the number
$$\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}$$
Let us call this number $c$. There are two things $c$ could be: irrational or rational. If $c$ is rational we are done; if it is irrational we now raise $c$ to the power of $\sqrt{2}$ to get
$$c^\sqrt{2} = \left(\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}\right)^\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{2}^2 = 2$$
We note that this number is rational, and since we are assuming $c$ is irrational and we know $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational we are done.

**Edit:**
I should note that $c^2$ is known as the [Gelfond–Schneider constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_constant) and it was later proved that $c$ ***is*** irrational

Comment: Please explain the following step: How did you go from $\left(\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}\right)^\sqrt{2}$ to $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @kunjimamu do you know the exponent rule $\left(a^b\right)^c = a^{bc}$?? If not, it's a good one to know :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using $\log $ as the base 10 logarithm, then your computations are fine. A more immediate example would come to mind though:

$$a = e, b = \ln{2},\\
a^b = e^{\ln{2}} = 2, 2\in \Bbb{Q} $$

Where $e $ is Neper's number, the base of the natural logarithm, or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: I don't understand how is my computations wrong? @rSerrao

Comment: His math is correct.

Comment: He is denoting $\log$ the base 10 logarithm.

Comment: @kunjimamu sorry I didn't understand you were using  $\log $ as the base 10 logarithm. I am used to it being just the *"regular"* one, with base $e $

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly. The only thing I would do other than that is to generalize it to $a=\sqrt[n]{m}$ and $b=n\log_mk$ and from there prove that $a^b=k$. You could also just do $a\notin\mathbb{Q}$ and $b=\log_ak$, where $k\in\mathbb{Q}$. It isn't really necessary to prove that all irrational numbers produce irrational numbers, but it does show where you're coming from and make it look less like you just stumbled upon random numbers that worked.