# Is this a valid proof? If $a$ and $b$ are rational, $a^b$ is rational.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

1st: I took the contrapositive.
If $a^b$ is irrational, then a and b are irrational.

2nd: I found an example to disprove my contrapositive.
Let $a = 2$
Let $b = 1/2$
Both are rational.

$a^b = 2^{(1/2)} = \sqrt{2}$, which is irrational.

It's too difficult to do html formatting on my phone, so I apologize in advance. Thanks.

Comment: I fixed your formatting and made it in MathJax format.

Comment: You have an error in taking the contrapositive: Not ($a$ and $b$ are rational) = ($a$ is irrational) or ($b$ is irrational). But in fact, your counterexample works directly without bothering with the contrapositive.

Comment: [Similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029518/please-verify-my-proof-if-a-and-b-are-irrational-then-ab-is-irrational) (although no exactly same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, your proof is fine. You showed that for all a and b are rational numbers, a^b is not always rational, by *counterexample.* Unless you're going to prove the statement by contraposition, finding the contrapositive is unnecessary. Just for future reference, the contrapositive of "if a and b then d", is "if ~d then ~a or ~b" (this is due to DeMorgan's Law).

Answer (score 1):

Your counter example is completely valid way to prove that your statement is false.

Your statement is:

> Forall rational $a,b$, $a^b$ is also rational

We will say that $\lnot=$ the negative, so the negative of the statement is:

> $\lnot($Forall rational $a,b$, $a^b$ is also rational$)$

By DeMorgan's Law:

> **exists** rational $a,b$, $\lnot(a^b$ is also rational$)$

The negative of rational is irrational so we left with

> exists rational $a,b$, $a^b$  is irrational.

So a counter example proves the negative of the statement, i.e disprove the statement